# Unable to mock in unit test for Configuration in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito

I am getting issue while writing unit test for following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class XYZProvider {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.class);

    private final Operations operations;

    public XYZProvider(Operations operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void process() {
        try {
            File[] files = operations.process(Constants.DIR); <---HERE I AM GETTING NULL FOR OPERATIONS EVEN AFTER MOCKING
            ...
    }
```

`Operations` class is as follows:

```
@Component
public class Operations {
    public File[] process(String dir) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Test file is as follows:

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class XYZProviderTest {

 @Mock
 Operations operations;

 @InjectMocks
 XYZProvider xyzProvider;

 @Test
 public void test_Success() throws IOException {
   
    when(operations.process(Constants.DIR))
       .thenReturn(getFiles("tests/success"));
   
    xyzProvider.process();

    ...
}
```

While running unit tests, I am getting null for `operations`. I am not getting idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

```
when(operations.process(Constants.DIR))
```

You need to use a Matcher instead of Constans.DIR. In Mockito 2 this would be

```
when(operations.process(ArgumentMatchers.eq(Constants.DIR)))
```

And if your Operations is null in XYXProvider I would try:

```
 @Test
 public void test_Success() throws IOException {
    Operations operations = Mockito.mock(Operations.class);
    XYZProvider provider = new XYZProvider(operations);

    when(operations.process(Constants.DIR))
       .thenReturn(getFiles("tests/success"));
   
    xyzProvider.process();

    ...
}
```

If that works you can move this to a BeforeTest-Method. You can also try:

```
@Mock
Operations operations;

@InjectMocks
XYZProvider xyzProvider = new XYZProvider(operations);
```